# Access kubernetes resource information through api

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes config with recourse limits for each container, something similar to this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
```

Is it possible to retrieve requests and limits configuration through kubernetes api or any other way to access it?

Comment: Anything that can retrieve the Pod spec will include the resource constraints, from `kubectl get pod -o yaml` up through basic use of a Kubernetes SDK.  What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to retrieve requests and limits configuration through kubernetes api or any other way to access it?

Yes, everything in Kubernetes can be accessed via APIs. You can use the REST-API directly, but it is easiest to use a Kubernetes client library for your favorite programming language, because authentication can be a bit tricky otherwise.

### Access Kubernetes API with curl using proxy

Example of accessing the API using curl is documented in [Using kubectl proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#using-kubectl-proxy).

First, use `kubectl proxy` to access the API:

```
kubectl proxy --port=8080 &
```

Then use that port, e.g.:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/api/
```

with output:

```
{
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "10.0.1.149:443"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how to access REST-API directly please?

Comment: Sorry, which url to call to get resources and limits?

Comment: It is in the Pod API, see e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#podspec-v1-core

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your reply. Are you familiar with k8s java client? Could you please check my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75279588/get-kubernetes-pods-information-through-microservice