# Get Kubernetes pods information through microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, microservices

When sending request to api, it throws NPE at api.listPodForAllNamespaces step. Could you please advise, what should be the correct configuration here?

Comment: Where are you running your code? I use the go client and I got NPEs when I didn’t properly set up my environment variables.

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: The code is deployed in kubernetes cluster and I'm sending request to API through terminal using curl

Comment: tgdavies, i have updated initial post with full stack trace

Comment: Can you give details of the service account attached to this deployment, if no then you will need to create a service account with relevant permissions and attach to the deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says:

`pods is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:sds-test:default\" cannot list resource \"pods\"`

This means that the service account `default` in the namespace `sds-test` does not have the appropriate permissions to list pods. You are probably not specifying a service account when you deploy. K8s will automatically assign you the `default` service account.

You need to create a `ServiceAccount`. Grant it the required access using a `Role` and `RoleBinding`. Then update your `Deployment`/`Pod` to use your newly created `ServiceAccount`. Details of which can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply testfile. Is it possible to use existing service account, i see this when running "kubectl get serviceaccounts":
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
default   0         66

Comment: @vehk it is possible although not recommended. There is nothing special about the `default` service account so you can bind roles to it just like any other service account. Best practice though is to create a specific service account for your application so that you can follow the principle of least privilege. If you add the role to the default service account then anything that runs in that namespace will get those permissions.